# How to limit displayed data with "pages"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've a list with many data-row. I list them trough table-tags(see code), which makes a long list.

However, how do I limit them e.g. max 10 data-row per "page", with a small "previous/next"-button at the bottom to list/navigate to next 10 data-row([like google search-pages where it have the best place to dump bodies](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CDe4FFwVAAAhovj.png))

```
 public ActionResult Index() {
        var listAll = db.Reviews.Include(m => m.User);
        return View(listAll.ToList());           
  }
```

Comment: Use a paging mechanism using queries with `.Skip()` and `.Take()` - for example, using PagedList.MVC - [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, just what I were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Paging which will display only some records at a time and below the records the user will have the option to navigate, just like Google Search, you also have to change your controller to retrieve only the number of records being displaying to avoid hitting the database without need.

First thing, open NuGet Package Manager Console by Clicking Tools -> NuGet Package Manager ->Package Manager Console

Then type the following command

`Install-Package MVC4.Paging`

This will install a library that draws paging control below your table

Open your view and add the following code

```
@using MvcPaging
@model IPagedList<Your Model Class>

Put here your table that lists the items

<div class="pager">
    @Html.Raw(Ajax.Pager(
            new Options
            {
                PageSize = Model.PageSize,
                TotalItemCount = Model.TotalItemCount,
                CurrentPage = Model.PageNumber,
                ItemTexts = new ItemTexts() { Next = "Next", Previous = "Previous", Page = "" },
                ItemIcon = new ItemIcon() { First = "icon-backward", Previous = "icon-chevron-left", Next = "icon-chevron-right", Last = "icon-forward" },
                TooltipTitles = new TooltipTitles() { Next = "Next page", Previous = "Previous page", Page = "Page {0}." },
                Size = Size.normal,
                Alignment = Alignment.centered,
                IsShowControls = true,
                IsShowFirstLast = true,
                CssClass = ""
            },
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "post",
            }, new { controller = "YourController", action = "YourAction" }))
</div>

<link href="~/Content/paging.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Now, you have to change your controller action to be as below

```
      using MvcPaging;

      public ActionResult Index(int? page) {
            int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1;

            var results = db.Reviews.Include(m => m.User);
            results = results.OrderBy(a => a.Id);

            var totalCount = results.Count();
            var pagedResults = results.ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, defaultPageSize, totalCount);

        return View(pagedResults ;           
       }
```